# save array in a loop

Tags: python, arrays, loops, output

I have an array (popt) updated in a loop, which I want to save it in a file.

```
for k in range (1:N):
    # here I make "popt" array which is depend on k
    np.savetxt('test.out',popt)
```

because of overwrite problem, only the last updated popt is saved. How can I save all the data ,not only the last one, of this array?

```
for k in range (1:N)
    # here I make "popt" array which is depend on k
    np.savetxt('test.out',popt)
```

Answer (score 0):

You're directly specifying a file to the **savetxt()** function. I'd manually open the file and pass a file handle; this way you can tell Python to append to the file.

```
with open('test.out','a') as f_handle:
    np.savetxt(f_handle, popt)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to add your matrix to an existing ASCII file, you can
open this file in append mode and give the file handle to
numpy.savetxt :

```
f_handle = file('test.out', 'a')
np.savetxt(f_handle, popt)
f_handle.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

Or rather, if you intend to save the file once after the loop is processed, move the `np.savetext()` command out of the loop - de-indent it once. This might even have happened by mistake.